# Is the Off-canvas of zurb foundation possible to implement in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to implement the Off-canvas layout of Zurb Foundation on Angular 4 but I'm really having a hard time and there is not much information about how to do it.